# Is it possible to upgrade version of php on my remote hosting server?

Tags: php, web-hosting

I have a hosting server which provides me php version 5.2 but the application made by me require php version 5.4.So is there possible any way how can i upgrade that version of  php on my remote server without contacting the company which provides me the hosting service.

Comment: Of course.  But we can't even begin to tell you how (or whether it's a good idea) without knowing more about the server.  OS/distro/version would be a good start - and you should probably make sure that no-one else has already answered this on server fault (note the "search" bar at the top right) because questions that have already been answered tend to attract close votes (as duplicates) and down votes (because the author is lazy) around these parts.

Answer (score 2):

If it is actually your server (or even one you rent - as long as you have root/admin access) sure!

If it is a shared hosting account, or a fully managed server and you don't have root/admin access, then sadly no.  Most webhosting accounts are shared hosting. If you're not sure which it is, you probably have shared hosting.